# How to display buffered image in JLabel or JPanel?

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jlabel

I have this `JFrame` with `JLabel label1` but I cant make it display the image. How do I display the updated buffered image in the label every time the `showScreenShot()` is called by another class?

I'm using Eclipse WindowBuilder.

Here's the code:

```
public class TeacherDashBoard extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private BufferedImage img;
    private static TeacherDashBoard frame;
    private static JLabel label1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    frame = new TeacherDashBoard();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void showScreenShot(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
        label1.getGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, label1.getWidth(), label1.getHeight(), null);
    }

    public TeacherDashBoard() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 424);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        label1 = new JLabel();

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(29)
            .addComponent(label1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 210, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(591, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(96)
            .addComponent(label1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 104, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(333, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);

        pack();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a confusing mix of `null` layout, `GroupLayout` and `pack()`. Drop the first and figure out how to use the latter two.

Answer (score 4):

This is wrong on at least two different levels:

```
label1.getGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, label1.getWidth(), label1.getHeight(), null);
```

1. Don't call `getGraphics()` on components. The changes to the component will be ephemeral, as Swing components need to paint themselves when and as told to do so.
2. Don't use `null` as the image observer. Every component in AWT/Swing implements `ImageObserver`.

Instead use:

```
label1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
```